# Angular query builder module how to create query for nested property

Tags: angular, query-builder

I am creating a search page UI in Angular 8. I have installed the [angular2-query-builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-query-builder) module for this purpose.

The builder is working for basic one-level queries.

**Question:** How can I extend the builder to allow for nested fields?

This [question also has been asked](https://github.com/zebzhao/Angular-QueryBuilder/issues/90) by other developers in the github issues section of the repository. Apparently nesting can be achieved with the 'entities' but I was not able to find any documentation on how to achieve that. I only need *one* level of nesting unlike the github issues question linked above that is asking for multiple levels of nesting.

In the example here, I want to be able to generate a query for Item properties such as Item.Title, Item.Description, etc.

Data to query:

```
{
  RecordID: 123,
  RecordType: "Item",
  Items: [
    {
      Title: "A title 1",
      Description: "A description 1"
    },
    {
      Title: "A title 2",
      Description: "A description 2"
    },
    {
      Title: "A title 3",
      Description: "A description 3"
    },
  ]
}
```

Config object in the component that I have currently:

```
  config: QueryBuilderConfig = {
    fields: {
      RecordID: { name: 'RecordID', type: 'number' },
      RecordType: {
        name: 'RecordType',
        type: 'category',
        options: [
          { name: 'Item', value: 'Item' },
          { name: 'Project', value: 'Project' }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Config object I am trying to create or something similar to achieve the nested query (working as expected for top-level properties only):

```
  config: QueryBuilderConfig = {
    fields: {
      RecordID: { name: 'RecordID', type: 'number' },
      RecordType: {
        name: 'RecordType',
        type: 'category',
        options: [
          { name: 'Item', value: 'Item' },
          { name: 'Project', value: 'Project' }
        ]
      }
      Items: {
        Title: {
          name: Title,
          type: string
        },
        Description: {
          name: Description,
          type: string
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

QueryBuilder isn't actually reaching into your data source so it doesn't need to know its shape. The difficulty will be converting QueryBuilder's `query` (output) object into something that drives the queries of your data source. With an in-memory data source you could probably use something like Ramda.

To configure QueryBuilder, this is probably what you're looking for:

```
  //Initial query displayed when component is loaded...
  query = {
    condition: 'and',
    rules: [
      { field: 'RecordType', operator: '=', value: 'Item' },
      {
        condition: 'or',
        rules: [
          { field: 'Items.Title', operator: 'contains', value: '2' },
          { field: 'Items.Description', operator: 'contains', value: '2' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  //Mapping fields...
  config: QueryBuilderConfig = {
    fields: {
      RecordID: { name: 'Record ID', type: 'number' },
      RecordType: {
        name: 'Record Type', type: 'category', options: [
          { name: 'Item', value: 'Item' },
          { name: 'Project', value: 'Project' }
        ]
      },
      'Items.Title': { name: 'Item Title', type: 'string' },
      'Items.Description': { name: 'Item Description', type: 'string' }
    }
  }
```